# WSO2 ESB with CEP doesn't work

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB v.4.8.1 and WSO2 CEP v.3.1.0 and I want to integrate each other. The problem is that I fill IP Address, protocol, disable security connection, Authentication Port set 7711, Receiver Port set on 7611 and when event come to ESB in order to send to CEP I get this error:

```
ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for ssl://<ip_address>:<port>
```

but security connection is disable.
I turn off firewall, set security connection but this doesn't help.
Has anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: ERROR AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for ssl://:ip_address:port

Comment: I set this params in "BAM server profile" on ESB.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing this by creating a BAM Server profile and providing a CEP Thrift endpoint. I would suggest you to try this out on a single machine with CEP running on port offset. This will let you identify whether the issue is with your network. If your running CEP on port offset 1, Reciever port should be `7612` and Authentication port should be `7712`

Comment: Thx for quick answer, but I have two machines and offset is set 0.

Comment: Can you try on a single machine with Offset 1. If it works then the issue is in your network

Comment: Ok, I check ESB and CEP on single machine with offset, change ports, etc. and it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?